# Node.js: Native crypto module could not be used to get secure random number

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I'm using `serverless` and `"amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^4.5.3"` for auth and stumbled over the error: `Error: Native crypto module could not be used to get secure random number.` when using `CognitoUser.authenticateUser`.

There are several git issues opened with multiple solutions, saying the issue is fixed with the version `3.2.0`, but it's still happening in the latest verions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I've found to work is to install `amazon-cognito-identity-js@unstable`.

There is another mentioned solution by adding `global.crypto = require('crypto')` at the beginning of the file ( line 1 ), but it did not work for me.

I'm leaving the git issue link for more solutions if this one somehow doesn't work, and for more context.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/7098

Comment: Not working for me; I've tried `global.crypto` and various versions of `amazon-cognito-identity-js` in different permutations, in my `package.json`. Should the package be installed somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue when I was working with amazon cognito in nodejs.
After so many hit and trial i found the solution, just change the amazon-cognito-identity-js version to :

**"amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^4.5.4-unstable.6"**

and now it is working for me, hope it will save your time and will work for you all who is facing this issue.
Hit up you found this worthy.

Comment: duplicated answer is not necessary

Comment: @CataHotea this is not duplicate but exact solution i think it is more clear for the people who came across this for the first time.